# Getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: when generating python executable file using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable file for my python file which does prediction. This python file takes two input. One is input file and other is model pickle file. After creating the executable file when I run the .exe file it throws me below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import contractions
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "contractions\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "pkgutil.py", line 639, in get_data
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 205, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI108442\\contractions\\data\\contractions_dict.json'
[10632] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I looked at few solutions with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) but I am not sure how to use it.